# Android storing images for puzzle game

Tags: android, sqlite

Just looking for an opinion on what is the best approach to my issue. I have an idea for a puzzle game app for kids, part of which requires the user to select the correct image from 3 different options. A clue is given such as 'D is for...' and then 3 images are to be displayed. Example an Apple, a Dog and a Goat. If the user selects the Dog in this case the next letter is chosen. If the user selects incorrectly they are given another chance to select.

I'm not looking for a solution to this, I just want to know what the best way would be to store the images with the correct question. Would an SQLite DB be the best option? Initially it would just store 1 image with each letter, but would eventually be expanded to store multiple images with each letter so I'm thinking long term here.

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: i dont think there is a 'best' way. Using SQLite is one way. Using an xml or json file to define the questions and the answer for each is another. You can store the images in the `assets/` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store it all in a json file.  I think SQLite will be overkill for this.

```
[
  {
    "letter":"c",
    "images":[
    "image_cat",
    "image_car"
    ]
  },
  {
    "letter":"d",
    "images":[
    "image_dog",
    "image_duck",
    "image_desk"
    ]
  }
]
```

Then you could parse out the json into an Array of objects easily enough.

Then in res/drawable/hdpi/ you can have 
image_cat.png
image_car.png
image_dog.png
image_duck.png
image_desk.png

Then to load those images from resources, use something like:

```
int resourceId=Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getContext().getPackageName());
if(resourceId != 0){
 Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
}
```

If you would rather store the images in assets, you could do this:

```
InputStream ims = getAssets().open(imageName);
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
```